# wicket 9: Testing page rendering. How To find a path to a component, link, etc

Tags: wicket

I want to use wicket tester to test my web application, however I'm totally lost on
what is a path and how to come up with one while testing certain components and behaviour

i.e

```
public void executeAjaxEvent(final String componentPath, final String event);
```

How does one come up with a componentPath?

I'm trying to brute force the path of this piece code, so that I could click optionLink, but still no luck, testing seems to be pointless endeavor as there are no way to find a path

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li wicket:id="options">
    <a href="#" wicket:id="optionLink">
    </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `wicketTester.debugComponentTrees()` to print the Page's children paths.

Answer (score 0):

A component path is a sequence of wicket:id separated by a colon and from the page to the specific component.

In your case:

```
options:0:optionLink
```

Note that repeaters add additional counters in between, thus the number for the n-th list item.

With DebugSettings#setComponentPathAttributeName() you can specify an HML attribute that should be used to write each component's path into the markup.